# How to configure nginx and uWSGI for Django project

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I am trying to configure nginx + uWSGI for Django project on local machine..but nginx and uWSGI not interacting with each other..

I have put nginx configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` which is :

```
    upstream django {
    # connect to this socket
    # server unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;    # for a file socket
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;      # for a web port socket
    }

server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      4321;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name localhost;   # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    #Max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste


    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # or the uwsgi_params you installed manually
        }
    }
```

And then i used this command to start uWSGI:

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8001 --chdir /home/vaibhav/TRAC/coupon-rest-api/couponRestApi/ --wsgi-file couponRestApi/wsgi.py --master --processes 4 --threads 2 --stats 127.0.0.1:9191
```

uWSGI is working but nginx + uWSGI not ..please tell me what i am doing wrong here...

nginx logs:

```
2013/05/11 11:12:56 [warn] 6563#0: server name "http://localhost/" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:30
2013/05/11 11:12:56 [emerg] 6563#0: unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:79
2013/05/11 11:16:01 [emerg] 8352#0: unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:79
```

I found the error in the nginx congiguration but now when i open Django admin panel the layout is distorted ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try /usr/local/lib/python2.7/sites-packages/django/